# カラオケのデンモクのようなあいうえお表を作りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby on railsを使っています。

- Initial # あ~を

  - id
  - name
  - initial_group_id
- InitialGroup # あかさたなはまやらわ

  - id
  - name

というモデルがあります。

これを使ってカラオケのデンモクのような「あいうえお表」を作りたいのですが、効率のいいプログラムのまわしかたがわかりません。

テーブルタグでイメージはこんな感じです。

```
なたさかあ
にちしきい
ぬつすくう
ねてせけえ
のとそこお
```

Comment: 50音表を出力したい&そのひらがなをidとしてリレーションを作るなら、埋め込んだ二次元配列を回すとか、あるいはテーブルをベタに書いてしまってもよさそうです。そのためだけにDB使うことはないかなあと。

Comment: やりたいことのイメージがハッキリと伝わってこないので、保存されているデータの具体例や「効率は悪いが自分で考えてみたコード」も追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

モデルの使い方が逆ではないかと思います。
「あ」というモデルに作品を登録するのではなく、
作品にinitialというカラムがあるのが普通の設計ではないかと思います。
あいうえお表はベタ書きで作ってしまって、リンクでパラメータとして投げてしまえば良いでしょう。